# Pandas remove strings after character occurance

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove the last occurrence of the string where there is a hyphen(-) leaving all the other strings alone that do not mean that criteria:

| Name1 | ID | ID_SPLIT | ID_SPLIT2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FUH-V2 | FUH07V2NUM |  |  |
| FUH-V2 | FUHV2-DEN | FUHV2 | FUHV2 |
| FUH-V2 | FUH30V2NUM |  |  |

```
df['ID'].str.split('-').str[:-1].str.join('-')
```

Comment: it's unclear what is the input and output, `df['ID_SPLIT']` doesn't contain hyphens

Comment: Fixed. my issue is it removed any string that doesn't have a -. Ideally I need this to fit multiple variations of ID.  (e.x. -DEN or me continously removing the last '-XXX' characters while preserving all else

Comment: Can you have more than one hyphen? If yes what should happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is to remove the last `-XXX` (if existing), then just do that with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['out'] = df['ID'].str.replace(r'-[^-]*$', '', regex=True)
```

Example:

```
    Name1             ID ID_SPLIT ID_SPLIT2         out
0  FUH-V2     FUH07V2NUM     None      None  FUH07V2NUM
1  FUH-V2      FUHV2-DEN    FUHV2     FUHV2       FUHV2
2  FUH-V2     FUH30V2NUM     None      None  FUH30V2NUM
3  FUH-V2  FUHV2-FOO-DEN     None      None   FUHV2-FOO
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CNvo5m/1)